# How do I use $('document').bind('pageinit') properly in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, page-init

So I understand that jQuery Mobile uses $('document').bind('pageinit') instead of $(document).ready() because they use Ajax. [see here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)  But I'm having trouble getting it to work.  For instance, I got this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.scrollingtext').bind('marquee', function() {
var ob = $(this);
var tw = ob.width();
var ww = ob.parent().width();
ob.css({ right: -tw });
ob.animate({ right: ww }, 10000, 'linear', function() {
ob.trigger('marquee');
});
}).trigger('marquee');

});
```

which works fine, but than I change it to this:

```
$('document').bind('pageinit', function(){
    $('.scrollingtext').bind('marquee', function() {
    var ob = $(this);
    var tw = ob.width();
    var ww = ob.parent().width();
    ob.css({ right: -tw });
    ob.animate({ right: ww }, 10000, 'linear', function() {
    ob.trigger('marquee');
    });
    }).trigger('marquee');

    });
```

And its a dud.  How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

`document`should not be between quotes. Additionally, it should be applied to pages (div with a `data-role="page"` property).

```
$(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]', function() {
```

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tMMfD/)

Comment: I tried that on several features that work with `$('document').ready(function() {` but no dice.  Thanks a bunch for trying.  I'm not sure whats up

Comment: Do you have a data-role=page div ? Could you peharps set a jsfiddle so that I can take a look at the the code as a whole ?

Comment: I have added the link to a fiddle in my answer where it works with pageinit (there is a slight bug remaining though: the animation starts only after the 10s cycle)